# Download all of someone else's Facebook photos

Tags: facebook, download

Is there a way to download all the photos from a Facebook user in a single click way?

There are several tools which will download every photo in an album, but if the user has many albums then even that can become tedious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. This isn't allowed per [section 3 clause 2 of Facebook's Terms of Service](http://www.facebook.com/legal/terms):

> You will not collect users' content or information, or otherwise access Facebook, using automated means (such as harvesting bots, robots, spiders, or scrapers) without our permission

The popular album downloader [PhotoJacker was abandoned](http://www.photojacker.com/post/2960957283/photojacker-shutdown) because of that. (Disclosure: The former developer is my friend.)